# fetch , GET запросы , аргументы

Tags: javascript, get, fetch

Есть проблемы и пара вопросов.

По условиям нужно из url1 принять объект и добавить `{ключ : значение}` к url2

- Можно ли подобное сделать через `.then`?
- Каким методом можно еще получить `{ключ : значение}` по отдельности?
- Почти всегда происходит GET : 500 ,
          Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0

  ```
  const url1 = "https://url1.com/?";
  const url2 = "https://url2.com/?";


  async function ticketsMain() {

      let response = await fetch(url1);
      let obj = await response.json();

      for (item in obj) {}
      let response2 = await fetch(`${url2}${item}=${obj[item]}`);
      let data = await response2.json();

      !data.stop ? ticketsMain() : data;
  }

  ticketsMain();
  ```

Comment: посмотри на вкладке  Network (Сеть) что именно приходит в ответ на запрос. И какой именно запрос ты шлешь

Comment: 1. https://i.imgur.com/tVZlALq.png 2. https://i.imgur.com/NxfDMVH.png 
Вроде все запросы одинаковые.

Comment: ну как минимум для твоего searchId падает сервер :)

Comment: меня одного смущает, что у него второй запрос выполняется вне цикла.

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев , не одного. Я только учусь, как сделать лучше?

Comment: @lex, у тебя первый fetch работает? получает результат?

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев да, {searchId: "55jy5"} теперь это значение нужно подставить в url2, каждый запрос id меняется.
Парсить до тех пор, пока не получишь объект со значение true и уже с ним работать